# Selenium IDE - Go back one page, if an error is returned

Tags: selenium-ide

I was given a task to retrieve a rather large number of PDF files from the clunky front end system of a former contractor. One must enter the file name, search, revalidate the file five or six times, then download the file.

I have written a script to do this in a loop, and so far, it's gotten the job done. However, if the file isn't found, it spits you to a new page, where it displays an error. You must then go back one page, and resume.

My issue is that I can't quite find a way to tell Selenium IDE "if you see this error, go back one page and resume" or "if the page changes, go back one page and resume."

Is it possible for Selenium IDE to follow an If command like this?

I have downloaded and installed all of the relevant plugins.

My script is as follows:

```css
    <!--Begin loop-->
    <tr>
     <td>loadTestData</td>
     <td>file://C:\[[the file path]]\test_data.xml</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>while</td>
     <td>!testdata.EOF()</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>nextTestData</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>echo</td>
     <td>bizcase_filename=${bizcase_filename}</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>type</td>
     <td>id=srch</td>
     <td>${bizcase_filename}</td>
    </tr>
    <!--Begin revalidation (5 times)-->
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=input.button</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>pause</td>
     <td>5000</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=td &gt; img</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>select</td>
     <td>id=action</td>
     <td>label=Revalidate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>//input[@value='Run']</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>id=pbStop</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>pause</td>
     <td>5000</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=td &gt; img</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>//input[@value='Run']</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>id=pbStop</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>pause</td>
     <td>5000</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=td &gt; img</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>//input[@value='Run']</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>id=pbStop</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>pause</td>
     <td>5000</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=td &gt; img</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End revalidation, retrieve file-->
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>//td[5]/a</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End loop-->
    <tr>
     <td>endWhile</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Test_data.xml, where I store all the file names, looks like this:

```html
<testdata>
 <test bizcase_filename="filename 1" />
 <test bizcase_filename="filename 2" />
 <test bizcase_filename="filename 3" />
</testdata>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use build in function called `storeElementPresent`

For example:

```
storeElementPresent id="error" x
```

And now, object "error" is stored in variable x.

Then you can call it with `gotoIf` function available from `goto_sel_ide` extension.

Example:

```
gotoIf ${x}==true errorVisible
gotoIf ${x}==false errorNotVisible
label errorVisible
goto tryAgain //tryAgain is a label set in right place
label errorNotVisible
goto Continue
label Continue
```

I hope you get the point. You can also use "if" statement by javascript.

Example (not related to your code):

```
storeElementPresent id=gbqfbb x /
click javascript{if(storedVars['x'] == true){this.browserbot.findElement('id=gbqfbb').click();}}
```

Hope it helps!